# Autorun Java programms at specific time on windows

Tags: java, windows

I'm interested, is there any good method for running **java programms** (*for example tests*) at any specific time on Windows?
Just can't find anything good as of now.

Comment: Windows scheduled tasks?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task

Comment: Off topic: the fact that these are Java programs that you want to run does not make this a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

*Schedule java programs externally*

For example via Windows Task Scheduler, windows version of crontab, etc. The scheduler invokes a script which runs your java program.

*Schedule java programs inside the jvm*

For example quartz scheduler. Your java program is running all the time, and it "wakes up" to perform specific actions.

*Integrate into a specific tool*

Since you mention running tests you could configure them to run in Jenkins.